# WebAudioAPI AnalyserNode is not working on mobile with MediaElementAudioSourceNode

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext, visualizer

I am trying to make an audio visualizer in html/javascript using the Web Audio API and I want it to work on mobile phones too.

I have my audio as a local file. Now I found two ways to import it, either using `new Audio(src)` or asynchronously using an `XMLHttpRequest`. The first method gets me a `HTMLMediaElement` that is way easier to work with and faster to load. As I want the visualizer to be controlled by the user, I need to be able to quickly change the audio source or the current seek position. The second one gives a buffer that needs to be decoded and is less suited for what I want.

Everything works fine on desktop, but for some reason I cannot make the analyser work on mobile using the first method. It works either without the analyser, either using `XMLHttpRequest`.

Here is my code setup (I'm using a local server to prevent CORS issues):

```
let audioURL = './audio.mp3'
let audioCtx, source, analyser

// Init the audio context after the first valid user interaction
window.addEventListener('click', initAudioContext) // Desktop support
window.addEventListener('touchend', initAudioContext) // Mobile support

function initAudioContext() {
    // Create the audio context
    audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
    audioCtx.resume()  // Needed for mobile/iOS support

    // Create an AnalyserNode
    analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser()

    // Create the source node element (this part has an issue)
    connectSource()

    // Remove the listeners as the audio context must be setup only once
    window.removeEventListener('click', initAudioContext)
    window.removeEventListener('touchend', initAudioContext)
}
```

Now here are 3 implementations of `connectSource` that gives me various results :

The first implementation is using the most basic method, and skipping entirely the analyser. This code works on both mobile and desktop and the audio plays after the first click/touch, but I don't get the audio data as there's no analyser.

```
function connectSourceWithoutAnalyser() {
    // Create an audio HTMLMediaElement and play it
    const audio = new Audio(audioURL)
    audio.play()
}
```

The second implementation is the one I'm aiming for, I'm still using the `Audio` element however I create a source node to use with the analyser. This implementation works fine for Desktop, but not for mobile (no audio at all on Safari or Chrome for iOS).

```
function connectMediaElementSource() {
    // Create an audio HTMLMediaElement
    const audio = new Audio(audioURL)

    // Use it to create a MediaElementAudioSourceNode
    source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio)

    // Connect the source to the analyser, then the analyser to the audio context's destination
    source.connect(analyser)
    analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination)

    audio.play() // Play the audio
}
```

Note that even if I remove the analyser and connect this new source directly to the destination by replacing `source.connect(analyser); analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination)` with `source.connect(audioCtx.destination)`, it doesn't work for mobile, so maybe the issue is more related to `createMediaElementSource()` than the AnalyserNode.

Finally the third implementation is using `XMLHttpRequest`. This one works fine for both mobile and desktop but as I stated earlier, I lose the reference to HTMLMediaElement and it's not something I want at all :

```
function connectBufferSource() {
    // Setup an XML Request
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('GET', audioURL, true)
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer'

    request.onload = function() {
        // Decode the response using the audio context
        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
            // Create an AudioBufferSourceNode
            source = audioCtx.createBufferSource()
            source.buffer = buffer // copy the buffer
            
            // Connect the source to the analyser, then the analyser to the audio context's destination
            source.connect(analyser)
            analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination)

            // Since there's no media element, we can't use play() and must use source.start()
            source.start()
        })
    }

    // Send the XML request
    request.send()
}
```

Is there a way to make the second implementation using an `AnalyserNode` as well as an `HTMLMediaElement` work for both mobile and desktop  ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this on mobile, but here's another approach using `createMediaStreamSource` instead of `createMediaElementSource`. will it work?

```js
let audioURL = './deskbell (mp3cut.net).wav';
let audioCtx, source, analyser
var canvas = document.querySelector(".canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Init the audio context after the first valid user interaction
window.addEventListener('click', initAudioContext) // Desktop support
window.addEventListener('touchend', initAudioContext) // Mobile support

function initAudioContext() {
  // Create the audio context
  audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
  audioCtx.resume() // Needed for mobile/iOS support            // <---- is it?

  // Create an AnalyserNode
  analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser()

  // Create the source node element (this part has an issue)
  connectSource()

  // Remove the listeners as the audio context must be setup only once
  window.removeEventListener('click', initAudioContext)
  window.removeEventListener('touchend', initAudioContext)
}

function createMediaStreamSource() {
  const audio = new Audio(audioURL)
  const stream = audio.captureStream();

  audio.play().then(_ => {
    source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
    source.connect(analyser)
    visualize(analyser)
  });
}

function connectSource() {
  // connectSourceWithoutAnalyser();
  // connectMediaElementSource();
  createMediaStreamSource()
}

function visualize(analyser) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var midpointY = canvas.height * 0.5;
  var pixelSize_y;
  var pixelSize_x = canvas.width / analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  pixelSize_y = canvas.height * 0.5;
  var data = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  var draw = function() {
    analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(data);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    var _g1 = 0;
    var _g = data.length;
    while (_g1 < _g) {
      var i = _g1++;
      ctx.lineTo(i * pixelSize_x, data[i] * pixelSize_y + midpointY);
    }
    ctx.stroke();

    int_id = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };
  draw();
};
```

```html
<h1>
  click for sound and visualization
</h1>
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: This works on Desktop, unfortunately after trying and looking at the docs, it seems that the `captureStream` method of an `HTMLMediaElement` isn't supported on Safari for iOS (https://caniuse.com/?search=captureStream). It still doesn't work for Chrome/Safari on iOS